# willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration is deprecated. Implement viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I got a list of deprecated warning once I updated my xcode to xcode9 and I have no Idea how to fix it

- 'willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Implement viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: instead
- 'willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Implement viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: instead
- 'didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0
- 'interfaceOrientation' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0

  ```
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];

      [self.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

      if (!_viewFirstAppeared) {
          _viewFirstAppeared = YES;

          void(^applyViews)(void) = ^{
              [self.centerController.view removeFromSuperview];
              [self.centerView addSubview:self.centerController.view];

              [self doForControllers:^(UIViewController* controller, IIViewDeckSide side) {
                  [controller.view removeFromSuperview];
                  [self.referenceView insertSubview:controller.view belowSubview:self.slidingControllerView];
              }];

              [self setSlidingFrameForOffset:_offset forOrientation:_offsetOrientation];
               self.slidingControllerView.hidden = NO;

               self.centerView.frame = self.centerViewBounds;
               self.centerController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
               self.centerController.view.frame = self.centerView.bounds;
              [self doForControllers:^(UIViewController* controller, IIViewDeckSide side) {
                  controller.view.frame = self.sideViewBounds;
                  controller.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
              }];

              [self applyShadowToSlidingViewAnimated:NO];
          };

          if ([self setSlidingAndReferenceViews]) {
              applyViews();
              applyViews = nil;
          }

          dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.001 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
              if (applyViews) applyViews();
              [self setSlidingFrameForOffset:_offset forOrientation:_offsetOrientation];
              [self hideAppropriateSideViews];
          });

          [self addPanners];

          if ([self isSideClosed:IIViewDeckLeftSide] && [self isSideClosed:IIViewDeckRightSide] && [self isSideClosed:IIViewDeckTopSide] && [self isSideClosed:IIViewDeckBottomSide])
              [self centerViewVisible];
          else
              [self centerViewHidden];
          }
      else if (_willAppearShouldArrangeViewsAfterRotation != UIDeviceOrientationUnknown) {
          for (NSString* key in [self.view.layer animationKeys]) {
              [self.view.layer animationForKey:key].duration);
          }

          [self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
          [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
          [self didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:_willAppearShouldArrangeViewsAfterRotation];
      }

      [self.centerController viewWillAppear:animated];
      [self transitionAppearanceFrom:0 to:1 animated:animated];
      _viewAppeared = 1;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 6):

I was just searching for the same exact thing and found something in iOS documentation and after reading it and since I have users who still have iOS 8. I kept the old two function and add the new one to it.

```
// old ones
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [self handleInterfaceOrientation];
}

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
    [self handleInterfaceOrientation];
}
// the new method
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        // what ever you want to prepare
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        [self handleInterfaceOrientation];
    }];
}

- (void)handleInterfaceOrientation {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
         // Landscape
    } else {
        // Portrait
    }
}
```